# Chrome displays Google search results page incorrectly

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

I have trouble in viewing Google search results in chrome.While other websites are displayed perfectly but the google search results looks like this...
[image: Google search results in chrome]

These are things I have tried:

- Restarted Chrome,
- Incognito Mode with all addons disabled
- Restarted the computer

**Additional info:**
OS VERSION:Windows 7 64 bit
Chrome version: 49

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is a software called  **WAJAM** Which is *capable of altering the Google search result page* to show ads and recommendation. 
I uninstalled the software and Everything works fine. 
Thanks for your support :)